# logstash unexpectedly stopped

Tags: java, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have set up a logstash with redis architecture to handle my logs. The way I have organized it is:

`logstash ---> redis ---> logstash ---> elasticsearch`

but the problem that occurred is that after parsing nearly 1.25 million logs a java exception is thrown.

In my `logstash.err` log file, the exception appears as

```
Exception in thread "<file" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:869)
    at org.jruby.RubyThread.exceptionRaised(RubyThread.java:1221)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I think that this exception might be thrown because of logstash unable to open/close a file. So what can I do to rectify this error? The way that my input configuration is set for my first logstash server to send the logs is:

```
input {
    file {
        start_position => "beginning"
        path => [
            "/var/logstash_logs/child1/nginx/*log*",
            "/var/logstash_logs/child2/nginx/*log*",
            "/var/logstash_logs/child3/nginx/*log*"
        ]
    }
}
```

And the way output is sent is like this:

```
output {
    redis {
        host => "X.X.X.X"
        key => "logstash"
        data_type => "list"
    }
}
```

There are no errors in the logs of logstash server with redis installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one problem here is with JRuby, which is trying to call `Thread.stop(Throwable obj);`, a deprecated method that throws `UnsupportedOperationException` and totally messes up the actual source of the error (the `Throwable` parameter).

So currently you can only guess what the actual problem is, and guessing is never good.

One idea is to set a breakpoint on `RubyThread.exceptionRaised();` and run it through a debugger. That should allow you to find out what the original `Throwable` is, and then you can get to the source of the problem.

You should also check if there exists a bug ticket for JRuby about this, and possibly update your JRuby.

Comment: Updated my JRuby and restarted the logstash. Hope that works fine. And about the `RubyThread.exceptionRaised();` breakpoint, I can't figure out how to set a breakpoint in my logstash config file. Can you please help me on how to do that? Thanks! :)

Comment: You can't set breakpoints in config files, but it would be quite a hassle to get a breakpoint inside JRuby. Go look around in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues) to see if they're aware of this bug.

Comment: Well, I submitted a new bug to them anyways. Seems the current version still has that bug.

Comment: Okay, hope they issue a solution soon. For me, the error is being thrown every 90 minutes when the files are being read. You can add that to the issue as well if it is of any relevance.

Comment: @KeshavAgarwal I doubt they will issue a solution any time soon (you might still want to follow the bug ticket to see what happens). If you're not very familiar with Java, it will probably be a lot of work to debug the cause at the moment.

Comment: I used kind of a hack to solve my case. I have set up a cron job for every hour to backup logstash's logs and restart it. And since the error occurs every 90 minutes, logstash doesn't come to halt.